# CodeIgniter - Which part of code is changing and updating session id?

Tags: database, codeigniter, session

In my script, CI updates the sessions table on database whenever it changes the session id. The thing is, I need to know that id whenever it changes. Simply I want to record it some different place on the database while keeping the actual recording. How could I do it?

Comment: I better not delete it, maybe someone will also search such an answer in the future.

Comment: Just to add my 2p, as long as the Q/A is valid, I think it should be preserved as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own answer. system/libraries/Session.php line:383 Of course the line number might differ, but if you search the following string, you'll learn where CodeIgniter is changing the session_id on database: `'session_id' => $new_sessid`

Comment: You may have a more fundamental issue - CI recycles sessions only when it thinks it needs to. You can, of course, disable this as you've said - but you should make 100% sure that you know WHY it was recycling and that preventing it isn't an issue - Eg. CI recycles the session every so often to make it harder for stolen sessions to be used to authenticate against your site - Did you mean to remove this security feature?. If I were you, I'd find out WHY it's recycling and fix that instead - most likely it's simply the session timeout setting in config but it could be a number of things

Comment: (If it would help, I'm happy to go through it with you and track down the underlying cause)

Comment: @Basiclife, well, either the question that I asked is not obvious (it probably is not obvious, my bad), or you misunderstood me. :) You are right about the security issues. I don't want to broke it, I want this to run in parallel with my session-based shopping-basket. That's why I asked where CodeIgniter changes the session id in the database - because when it changes, the one in the shopping-basket table should change also.

Comment: I think what you want to be doing in this case is making sure your shopping basket can cope with the session Id changing mid-flow. I know that's likely to be a pain but it's the "correct" solution. An easier compromise might be to generate a new, unique Id and store it in the session - then use that in the cart. The session Id itself may change but the contents shouldn't

Comment: I thought using of a new unique id, but figured out a much easier way. I added a new line to the Session class, so everytime the session id changes, the one in the shopping basket table will change also. It works fine now. :)